# Multiple Video Streams over RTCPeerConnection

Tags: javascript, video, webrtc, video-streaming, html5-video

I am using rtsotowebrtc from DeepEch to stream my IP cameras over WebRTC. My client code is as follows:

```
var webrtc_con = new RTCPeerConnection({
              iceServers: [{
                  urls: ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]
              }],
              sdpSemantics: 'plan-b'
          })
          webrtc_con.ontrack = function (event) {

              videoEl.srcObject = event.streams[0]

              if (videoEl.readyState >= HTMLMediaElement.HAVE_CURRENT_DATA) {
                  videoEl.play().catch(() => {
                  });
              } else {
                  videoEl.oncanplay = () => {
                      videoEl.play().catch(() => {
                      });
                  };
              }

          }
          webrtc_con.addTransceiver('video', {direction: 'sendrecv'})
          webrtc_con.onnegotiationneeded = async function handleNegotiationNeeded() {
              const offer = await webrtc_con.createOffer()

              await webrtc_con.setLocalDescription(offer)

              try {
                  fetch(url, {
                      method: 'POST',
                      body: new URLSearchParams({data: btoa(webrtc_con.localDescription.sdp)})
                  })
                      .then(response => response.text())
                      .then(data => {
                          try {
                              webrtc_con.setRemoteDescription(
                                  new RTCSessionDescription({type: 'answer', sdp: atob(data)})
                              )
                          } catch (e) {
                              console.warn(e)
                              console.warn(`Stream ${url} Not Found!`)
                          }
                      })
              } catch (e) {
                  console.warn('Server maybe offline?')
              }
          }
```

I am currently only able to get one stream per WebRTC connection. How can I get multiple video streams over one connection? Thank you for your help.